# How to install Mars [Mips] on Ubuntu 14.04 ?

Tags: 14.04

I need to install Mars for Mips assembler environment  , can anyone help?

Comment: It looks like this question is about  [MIPS Assembly and Runtime Simulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/) - why don't you ask them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Download file from [Official Web-site](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/download.htm) Save the jar file in some folder. Open the Terminal in that folder. Rename the jar file to `"Mars.jar"` for convenience. Open the terminal and use the BASH command  `java -jar Mars.jar`

Answer (score 2):

Install openJDK Java 7 runtime (it's in the repositories). 
Right-click on the MARS app.--> properties-->permissions --> tick the "execute" box. 
If openJDK is installed, when you right-click on the MARS app you will see the option to open it with it.

That's it! 
Bests